# text-overflow: ellipsis - Exibindo texto quando passar o mouse em cima

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu fiz aparecer "..." ao final de um titulo muito grande, quando passo o mouse em cima dele eu já consigo fazer ele exibir o resto do título, mas ele não usa uma quebra de linha.

Como quero que funcione? Ao passar o mouse em cima ele remova "..." e exiba o texto todo com uma quebra de linha no lugar que estavam os "..." ou seja, o texto cai para uma segunda linha.

Estou usando bootstrap.css bootstrap.mim.css e o meu shop-homepag.css (mais abaixo está o código na integra).

a classe `p.legenda` faz os "...", tentei usar fazer `p.legenda:hover`, mas não funcionou.

O que preciso fazer para ter essa quebra de linha?

shop-homepag.css:

```html
/*!
 * Start Bootstrap - Shop Homepage HTML Template (http://startbootstrap.com)
 * Code licensed under the Apache License v2.0.
 * For details, see http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.
 */

body {
    padding-top: 70px; /* Required padding for .navbar-fixed-top. Remove if using .navbar-static-top. Change if height of navigation changes. */
}

.slide-image {
    width: 100%;
}

.carousel-holder {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.carousel-control,
.item {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

.caption {
    height: 130px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.caption h4 {
    /*white-space: nowrap;*/
    white-space:pre;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
}

.thumbnail img {
    width: 100%;
}

.ratings {
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    color: #d17581;
}

.thumbnail {
    padding: 0;
    border: none;
    margin-bottom:5px;
}

.thumbnail .caption-full {
    padding: 9px;
    color: #333;
}

footer {
    margin: 50px 0;
}
p{
    margin-left:0;
    margin-bottom:0;
}
p.legenda{
    white-space:pre;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    width: 200px;
}

p.legenda:hover{
    text-overflow: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 200px;
}



p.tempo{
    font-size:12px;
}
```

O que precisa ser mudado para ele quebrar a linha.

SOLUÇÃO:

Mudei as classes legendas para ficar como abaixo, agora os ... aparecem e se passar o mouse em cima o resto do titulo aparece com a quebra de linha

```html
.legenda p{
    white-space:pre;
    overflow:hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.legenda p:hover{
    white-space:normal;
    text-overflow: inherit;
    overflow: visible;
}

.legenda{
     width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o título for maior que o div onde ele está, automaticamente a linha será quebrada e o restante do texto irá para a linha de baixo. Então o que você precisa, basicamente é ter um tamanho definido no div pai onde esse título está.

Depois basta alterar a propriedade [`white-space`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) que você utiliza com valor `pre` para `normal`, que é o valor *default*. Com isso você já consegue obter o resultado que está buscando:

```css
.wrap {
  background: skyblue;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.wrap header {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: pre;
  width: 100%;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.wrap header:hover {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrap'>
  <header>Meu título enooooooooooooooooorme</header>
</div>
```